# On MathJobs, what does "Faculty contacts in our dept?" means?

Tags: mathematics, job-search

I've noticed that several MathJobs applications asks "Faculty contacts in our dept?", always with this exact, confusing wording.

I'm not clear what this means. Can someone explain?

Is it, "do you personally know anyone in our faculty?" or is it "who is the person in our faculty that's closest to your research area so that they can evaluate your application?"

Comment: I actually emailed MathJobs in January asking them to clarify this phrasing.  They said they'd think about it, but it looks like they didn't clarify it this year.

Answer (score 10):

This is a really really important question, and it's really important that the correct answer is option 2.  Most graduate students interpret it to mean 1, and this puts them at a disadvantage.  You should list any people in the department who might be interested in serving a postdoc mentor for you.  You should always list someone.

There are two main reasons for this:

1. On mathjobs you can run a search for all applicants who listed a given faculty member as a contact.  I always look at the applicants who list me as a reference.  Along with sending an email, this is the best way to assure that at least one person looks at your file.
2. When I served on the postdoc hiring committee I was responsible for looking through 20% of the applicants.  We're only going to hire a postdoc if there's a good research match for them in the department who is interested in mentoring them.  If I see a good file, one of the most important things is to make it easy for me to know which faculty member to mention the file to.  Sometimes I can work that out myself, but it's not always obvious.  Listing someone as faculty contact immediately indicates who I should email.

Comment: If there is no faculty contact to list, then is it worth applying?

Comment: I'd suggest trying harder to identify who is closest or talking to your advisor about who to list, but if there's really no one anywhere near you then your odds of getting a job there is vanishingly low and it probably isn't worth applying.

Comment: What happens if you leave it blank?

Comment: So, not all files get looked at?

Comment: Here there’s a hiring committee of 5 people who split up looking (briefly!) at all the files. But most faculty aren’t on the hiring committee and a file is much more likely to get a close look if someone tells the hiring committee they’re interested in it! If im not on the committee I’m certainly not reading dozens and dozens of files!

Answer (score 2):

It is more like the first of your options. If your name is mentioned to a member of their faculty, will they recognize the name and have a rough idea who you are. This doesn't necessarily mean they know you personally, maybe they have just read some of your papers and have seen you speak at a conference. But the point is that the faculty member should already be aware of you not just that they work in an area that fits with what you do.