# What does the question: "Any faculty contacts in our department?" mean?

Tags: mathematics, application, research-undergraduate

I am applying to some Math REUs this summer and on some applications I have the following question:

> Any faculty contacts in our department?

I suppose I just say "no," or "0," because I am applying from an external university and thus do not know any math faculty at the university.

I want to note that my question is not [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/140850/on-mathjobs-what-does-faculty-contacts-in-our-dept-means), which seems to be asking about graduate school applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it does happen that some undergraduate students have contacts in departments at other universities. (I know of such examples in my department.)

But if you literally never communicated with any faculty in the department running the REU, you should write "No."